# Multiple column with multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data look like:

```
   A   B   C   Month
0  1   3   5    Jan
1  1   2   3    Feb
```

I need to:
a) convert 'Month' to dummies

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['Month'],drop_first=True,prefix = 'm')
```

b) Multiply A / B / C with all dummies generated.
The only way I can think of doing this is

```
df_Feb = df2[['A','B','C']].multiply(df2['m_Feb], axis = "index")
df_March
...
```

and then join all newly created dataframe, which isn't very convenient. Is there is better way to approach this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create `MultiIndex` in both `DataFrame`s by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), so possible multiple each other:

```
df1 = df[['A','B','C']]
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df['Month'])

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, df2.columns])
df2 = df2.reindex(mux, axis=1, level=1)
df1 = df1.reindex(mux, axis=1, level=0)

df = df1 * df2
```

Last for correct ordering is used ordered `CategoricalIndex` and last flatten data columns with `f-string`s:

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
          "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    df.columns.get_level_values(0),
    pd.CategoricalIndex(df.columns.get_level_values(1),categories=months,ordered=True),
])
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
print (df)

   A_Jan  A_Feb  B_Jan  B_Feb  C_Jan  C_Feb
0      1      0      3      0      5      0
1      0      1      0      2      0      3
```